# Laravel new error displaying package (Ignition) causes error on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel's new error displaying package runs command at startup and it causes the error

> Process class relies on `proc_open`, which is not available on your PHP installation.

Here is error trace

```
at Process->__construct('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1', '/home/u7640462/congresssun.com/dev')
in AddGitInformation.php line 50

at AddGitInformation->command('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1')
in AddGitInformation.php line 25
```

It's shared hosting so I'm not able to change `php.ini` file effectively. I can't enable proc_open on php.ini

So how can I get away with this error?

Even if I set `.env` for production and close debugging it gives me the above error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can turn off the Git functionality by modifying [your `config/flare.php` configuration](https://github.com/facade/ignition/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=collect_git_information&type=) to set `flare.reporting.collect_git_information` to false.

This is [the only spot that uses the `Process` class](https://github.com/facade/ignition/search?q=process&unscoped_q=process) so it should resolve this issue, at least.

<sup>(Fundamentally, though, find a better web host that doesn't do this. You are likely to run into other issues with disabled functionality that may be much harder to work around.)</sup>

Comment: but when you turned it on, it runs git command and on shared hostings that causes error

Comment: @TeomanTıngır I said you should turn it *off*. It's on by default.